# How to merge json field with object array in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

how to merge

```
[{"k": 1,"v":{"a1": null}}, {"k": 2, "v":{"b1":"B1"}}, {"k": 3, "v":{"c1":"C1"}}]

[{"k": 1,"v":{"a1": "A1"}}, {"k": 2, "v":{"b1":"B1", "b2": "B2"}}]
```

expected result@

```
[{"k": 1,"v":{"a1": "A1"}}, {"k": 2, "v":{"b1":"B1", "b2": "B2"}}, {"k": 3, "v":{"c1":"C1"}}]
```

I tried the following one:

```
WITH merged_objects AS (
  SELECT k,
         jsonb_agg(v) as v
  FROM (
    SELECT elem -> 'k' as k,
           jsonb_each(elem -> 'v') as v
    FROM (
      SELECT jsonb_array_elements('[
        {"k": 1, "v": {"a1": null}},
        {"k": 2, "v": {"b1": "B1"}},
        {"k": 3, "v": {"c1": "C1"}}
      ]'::jsonb) as elem

      UNION ALL

      SELECT jsonb_array_elements('[
        {"k": 1, "v": {"a1": "A1"}},
        {"k": 2, "v": {"b1": "B1", "b2": "B2"}}
      ]'::jsonb) as elem
    ) subquery
  ) subquery
  GROUP BY k
)
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('k', k, 'v', v)) as merged_array
FROM merged_objects;
```

but the result isn't right. The value in v field has not been merged.

```
[{"k": 2, "v": [{"key": "b1", "value": "B1"}, {"key": "b1", "value": "B1"}, {"key": "b2", "value": "B2"}]}, {"k": 1, "v": [{"key": "a1", "value": null}, {"key": "a1", "value": "A1"}]}, {"k": 3, "v": [{"key": "c1", "value": "C1"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge JSONB values using the `||` operator. Here is an illustration. Please note the use of `coalesce` for handling unmatched JSON keys.

```sql
select jsonb_agg(coalesce(j1, '{}') || coalesce(j2, '{}')) as merged_array
from
  jsonb_array_elements('[{"k":1,"v":{"a1":null}},{"k":2,"v":{"b1":"B1"}},{"k":3,"v":{"c1":"C1"}}]'::jsonb) j1 
left outer join
  jsonb_array_elements('[{"k":1,"v":{"a1":"A1"}},{"k":2,"v":{"b1":"B1","b2":"B2"}}]'::jsonb) j2 
on (j1 ->> 'k') = (j2 ->> 'k');
```

Answer edited. You can use the above query as a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) too.
[DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/imxZ2NgJhySXnt1S8Tnfqz/0)

| merged_array |
| --- |
| [{"k": 1, "v": {"a1": "A1"}}, {"k": 2, "v": {"b1": "B1", "b2": "B2"}}, {"k": 3, "v": {"c1": "C1"}}] |